# Cluetip popup windows getting cutoff by browser

Tags: cluetip

```
jQuery('area').cluetip({
        sticky: true,
        positionBy: 'auto',
        width:370,
        dropShadow:false,
        closePosition: 'top',
        closeText: '',
        activation: 'click'
}
```

Straight to the point: when i click to activate popup windows, it's always at the right handside of where i click, even when there is not enough space. So for those it only shows some part to the cluetip as the rest is getting cutt off by browser window??

I am totally new to php and cluetip...

Comment: Hmmm... no answer yet either on stackoverflow that impossible.....i must have ask really dumb question ???

Answer (score 0):

About the only thing that can be done, by the looks of things, is use the `positionBy` parameter. But it doesn't work really in determining if the tip is cutoff, I have tried many cases myself.

The options are `auto, mouse, bottomTop, fixed`, but none of them work really, they all get cut off.

The only solution I found myself was to use `fixed` and set top and left manually and always have it in the same place.

```
j('.areaH').cluetip({
        positionBy: 'fixed',
        topOffset: 200,
        leftOffset: 100
    });
```

Unfortunately though you are stuck at that place holder. I guess you could take the action and to each thing that calls a cluetip call a wait segment of 1 second then re-position the cluetip window using jQuery.

This would be in an `onHover` event set off by the thing that calls the cluetip separately. But that's about it. I have tested this myself on FF and Chrome and in both it cuts off.

http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/#features

In the `onHover` event you can always use another jQuery plugin that waits for an element to exist then re-position, what you can do is in each element have your own `attr` that has the new position, or just call the elements `left` and `top` position using jQuery and move the Cluetip window to that +20 in each direction.